# calculating difference between timestamp values from same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filenames, python-datetime

I am working on converting the Blf file into Tab separated file. I am able to extract all the useful information from the file in a list below. I want to calculate the difference between timestamp values coming in one column. Please find attached my code so far:

```py
import can
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd

filename = open('C:\\Users\\shraddhasrivastav\\Downloads\\BLF File\\output.csv', "w")
log = can.BLFReader('C:\\Users\\shraddhasrivastav\\Downloads\\BLF File\\test.blf')

# print ("We are here!")
log_output = []

for msg in log:
    msg = str(msg).split()
    #print (msg)

    data_list = msg[7:(7 + int(msg[6]))]

    log_output_entry = [(msg[1]), msg[3], msg[6], " ".join(data_list), msg[-1]]
    log_output_entry.insert(1, 'ID=')
    test_entry = " \t ".join(log_output_entry)  # join the list and remove string quotes in the csv file

    filename.write(test_entry + '\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(log_output)
df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'ID', 'DLC','Channel']

filename.close()  # Close the file outside the loop
```

The output I am getting so far is below:

[image]

Under my first column, I want the difference between the timestamp values (**Example- 2nd row value - 1st row timestamp value... 4th row timestamp value - 3rd row timestamp value...and so on...** What should I add in my code to achieve this?

Below is the screenshot of how I want my file's Timestamp field to look like. (Calculating the difference between consecutive rows)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyarC.jpg)

Comment: I edited your formatting, I believe part of your question at the end was formatted into your code, check it over to see if it is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.shift`:

```
df['Time Delta'] = df['Timestamp'] - df['Timestamp'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)
```

Keep in mind that the file you currently have seems to have variable length between the columns in the text file you write to, so it might be hard to directly insert into pandas. Maybe following would work:

```
import can
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd

#filename = open('C:\\Users\\shraddhasrivastav\\Downloads\\BLF File\\output.csv', "w")
log = can.BLFReader('C:\\Users\\shraddhasrivastav\\Downloads\\BLF File\\test.blf')

# print ("We are here!")
log_output = []

for msg in log:
    msg = str(msg).split()
    #print (msg)

    data_list = msg[7:(7 + int(msg[6]))]

    log_output_entry = [(msg[1]), msg[3], msg[6], " ".join(data_list), msg[-1]]
    log_output_entry.insert(1, 'ID=')
    assert len(log_output_entry)==4
    log_output.append(log_output_entry)
    #test_entry = " \t ".join(log_output_entry)  # join the list and remove string quotes in the csv file

    #filename.write(test_entry + '\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(log_output)
df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'ID', 'DLC','Channel']
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='s')
df['Time Delta'] = df['Timestamp'] - df['Timestamp'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\shraddhasrivastav\\Downloads\\BLF File\\output_df.csv')

#filename.close()  # Close the file outside the loop
```

Comment: It is givin following error:
 ```df['Time Delta'] = df['Timestamp'] - df['Timestamp'].shift(periods=1, axis=0)
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: After the `df=pd.DataFrame(log_output)` you need to set the column names of the data frame, e.g. `df.columns = ['Timestamp', 'ID', 'DLC']`. Unfortunately from the image it is not clear how many columns will get loaded, so you will need to adjust the list to have a name for each column.

Comment: I did add the following as you mentioned. See the original post. Unfortunately, it didn't calaculate the difference between the timestamp fields. Can you take a look if I wrote something wring in my original code after your suggestion?

Comment: The one piece I did not consider was column types, where Timestamp column is still a string. `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='s')` before the  difference calculation should do the trick. Will expand existing answer.

Comment: can u edit your code you posted? I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: Code is edited. Keep in mind you will not see a difference in the file you write to as there you save the test_entry, not the data frame object itself. You can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for that `df.to_csv(C:\\Users\\shraddhasrivastav\\Downloads\\BLF File\\output_df.csv)`

Comment: I am a newbie. Can you tell where to add this inside the code? Sorry for asking a very basic question. It would be great if you can explain again in your original code.

Comment: Edited. No worries (so long as people don't get too zealous about what the question actually was). Hope this edit works!

Comment: I ran your edited code as it is but in my destination folder nothing changed. I mean I still can't see the timestamp values as the difference between two consecutive rows. Any reason why? Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Do you see a file named output_df.csv in the output folder?

Comment: No, I don't see the file in the output folder. I don't know why. I am running your code as is only.

Comment: although the code after running for sometimes throws the following error:
```line 155, in set_axis
    'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

Comment: Sorry was sleepy and forgot to append the `log_output_entry` in the `log_output` during one of the edits. This edit also contains an assert for correct log_output_entry size,  to guarantee you the right number of elements. I do not have personal experience with BLF files, so the last source of error is varying length of input (as DFs expected tabular format). Also disabled the creation of filename to speed up the process of dumping to csv file.

Comment: I had made a mistake in the assert statement by asserting log_output instead of log_output_entry. Edited in as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping so far. I ran the new code you edited it is giving the following error:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shraddhasrivastav/PycharmProjects/BLF/Text-blf.py", line 20, in <module>
    assert len(log_output_entry)==4
AssertionError```

Comment: That means that your part of the  code that parses the msg object returns variable length lists. I would recommend opening a separate question on correctly parsing the BLF file if you need help debugging it. If as a mvp you really only need the timestamps and timestamp diff,   comment out the assert and edit the corresponding lines `log_output.append(log_output_entry[0])` and `df.columns = ['Timestamp']`